# How to use the while loop to get the factorial of an integer without getting endless factorials back?

Tags: python, while-loop

I have to write a program that tells the user the factorial of any integer between 1 and 15 while using the while loop. I wrote the code below and the output gives me endless factorials/numbers.. Do you know what I did wrong? Thank you!

Update: I realized that I should use "while" for what num isn't, so I now have this code below, but it still says invalid syntax for the second "while".

```
# take input from the user
num = int(input("Please enter a number from 1 to 15: "))
factorial = 1

# check if the number is negative, positive or zero
while num < 0:
   num = int(input("Negative numbers don't have factorials! Please enter a number between 1 and 15: ")
while num > 15:
   num = int(input("Please enter a number between 1 and 15! ")
if num == 0:
   print("The factorial of 0 is 1")
else:
   for i in range(1,num + 1):
       factorial = factorial*i
   print("The factorial of",num,"is",factorial)
```

Comment: You never increment ``num``, so it never exceeds 16

Comment: *types 20 to pass the negative check, then sneaks -20 past the other*. `while not 0 < num < 15:` will do both in one check, so you can't zigzag between the tests.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this:

```
from math import factorial as factorial

while True:
    num = int(input("Please enter a number from 1 to 15: "))
    if 1 <= num <= 15:
        fact = factorial(num)
        print 'the factorial of {n} is {f}'.format(n=num, f=fact)
    else:
        num = int(input("Please enter a number from 1 to 15: "))
```

Comment: Nice answer. But what is difference between `from math import factorial as factorial` and `from math import factorial`?

Comment: Now if you don't give a number between 1 and 15 you are asked twice for it. You should remove the `else`.

Answer (score 0):

you have missed the braces at the end of `int()` funtion

```
# take input from the user
num = int(input("Please enter a number from 1 to 15: "))
factorial = 1

# check if the number is negative, positive or zero
while num < 0:
   num = int(input("Negative numbers don't have factorials! Please enter a number between 1 and 15: ")) # brace was missing
while num > 15:
   num = int(input("Please enter a number between 1 and 15! ")) # brace was missing
if num == 0:
   print("The factorial of 0 is 1")
else:
   for i in range(1,num + 1):
       factorial = factorial*i
   print("The factorial of",num,"is",factorial)
```

You might have meant like the below in order to loop until you get correct input:

```
# take input from the user
num = int(input("Please enter a number from 1 to 15: "))
factorial = 1
while(True):
    if num < 0:
       num = int(input("Negative numbers don't have factorials! Please enter a number between 1 and 15: ")) # brace was missing
       continue
    if num > 15:
       num = int(input("Please enter a number between 1 and 15! ")) # brace was missing
       continue
    if num == 0:
       print("The factorial of 0 is 1")
    else:
       for i in range(1,num + 1):
           factorial = factorial*i
       print("The factorial of",num,"is",factorial)
       break
```

Comment: The program runs now, but I can't use the secondary num input under the two while loops. Do you know why that is?

Comment: I have added the code, based on what you might be wanting.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a closing parenthesis:

```
while num > 15:
   num = int(input("Please enter a number between 1 and 15! "))
                                                              ^ here
```